# How do I initialize in Angular an object declared as an extern class?

Tags: angular, variables, initialization, declaration

how do I can initialize in Angular a variable:

```
datiIn: Metro;
```

of the extern class:

```
export class Metro {   constructor(
    public idt: string,
    public linea: string, // nome della linea
    public numchatting: number, // numero passeggeri in chat
    public tempo: number // orario partenza   ) {} }
```

because the Angular compiler reports:

> "Property 'datiIn' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned
> in the constructor.ts(2564)"

So I know that a Quick Fix is writing:

```
datiIn!: Metro;
```

or

```
datiIn: Metro | undefined;
```

but I want to initialize it. I understand that is wrong to write:

```
datiIn: Metro = new Metro();
```

but I don't know how to initialize this variable datiIn. Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

I understand it should be something like this...

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  private datiIn: Metro;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datiIn = new Metro();
  }
}
```

In the OnInit since this is the code that Angular executes once its component is initialized (but before the view is ready)